# Displaying the query using jquerybuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-builder

I used jQuery QueryBuilder (http://querybuilder.js.org/) to create the rules and generate JSON and store them in a database. Now,  I need to do the reverse operation. This means,that the input will be in the form of a JSON which would get parsed and display the rules in the UI in the same format of QueryBuilder for modification/deletion. Can someone provide pointers/sample code on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive this you have to use the ***setRules *** method --> [see documentation here](http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html#methods)

```
   var rules_json= {
      condition: 'AND',
      rules: [{
        id: 'price',
        operator: 'less',
        value: 10.25
      }, {
        condition: 'OR',
        rules: [{
          id: 'category',
          operator: 'equal',
          value: 2
        }, {
          id: 'category',
          operator: 'equal',
          value: 1
        }]
      }]
    };

    $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', rules_json);
```

Comment: Vladu Ionut: Thx. Could you pls let me know how can I display an existing rule in JSON format to appear in the UI?

Comment: var result = $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('getRules');
  
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  }

Comment: Vladu Ionut : Got it.  Thank you very much.